# What is the source for some Ashkenazim not reciting Lamnatzeiach on Isru Chag?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, minhag, isru-chag

[Mishnah Berurah 131:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.131.35?lang=bi) lists the following days on which Ashkenazim do not recite Lamnatzeiach (Tehillim 20) during weekday Shacharit between Ashrei and Uva LeTzion:

- Rosh Chodesh
- Chanukah
- Purim
- Erev Pesach
- Erev Yom Kippur
- Tish'ah BeAv
- Purim Katan

There is no mention of omitting Lamzatzeiach on Isru Chag.

However, I have been present in a number of Ashkenazi synagogues (mostly in Israel) where Lamazatzeiach was omitted on Isru Chag.

What is the source for this practice?

Comment: In Israel remember Isru Chag is a day that is Yom Tov for most Jews.

Comment: @DoubleAA https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82317/759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[R' Ya'akov Chayim Sofer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Chaim_Sofer) זצ''ל writes in [Kaf HaChayim to Orach Chayim 429:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.429.41?vhe=Kaf_Hachayim,_Orach_Chayim_vol._V-VIII,_Jerusalem_1910-1933&lang=he) that according to the [R' Ya'akov Moelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin) זצ''ל Lamenatzeiach is not said on Isru Chag. (see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8918&st=&pgnum=4))

Comment: It is also mentioned here before the psalm: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=331

Comment: [I don't understand your _e_ after the _m_ in your transliteration]